# Javascript adding Razor tags on client side, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I want to do something as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25062743/5837056

My question is, will the changes the javascript makes persist after post? Or will the view reload as just what's hardcoded in the .cshtml file?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

The view will reload as it was coded in the .cshtml file, however the razor code will be replace with injected html.

E.g. on the users end

```
@EditorFor(x=>x.Example)
```

Will be replaced by

```
<input type="text" id="Example" name="Example"/>
```

etc.

However if you make some conditional or iterative statements in razor that change the injected code depending on your model, you could influence the initial view.

For example - if you're displaying a collection of string editors based on the amount of objects passed, the code in the .cshtml file will change depending on that number.

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Items)
{
    @EditorFor(x=>item.Example)
}
```

Will be replaced by

```
<input type="text" id="Item_0_Example" name="Item_0_Example"/>
<input type="text" id="Item_1_Example" name="Item_1_Example"/>
<input type="text" id="Item_2_Example" name="Item_2_Example"/>
```

Thus, changing your base html code.

In the example you have linked - if the page is refreshed, the view will return to its original state.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to let the user add additional form inputs with a button, like in this mockup: https://jsfiddle.net/cinerobert/409k27ot/8/   (click "Yes" and then "Cash" and then try adding new recipients with the button at the bottom). But I need the extra inputs to persist after the form posts. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: If you use an IList<String> Items or whatever datatype/object type you need, you can map the dynamic list to the model using, 

<input type="text" name="Items[0]_Parameter" /> 

Where you replace 0 with the iterator value. 

Then when you post your page, the items will be bound to the list in the controller, you could then use this passed list for whatever purpose it is needed. If you need to display the view again, you could pass the objects back to the view and re-display them

Comment: Thank you. I have a bunch of experimenting to do to understand the excellent advice I have been given!